# how to use `tf.train.Saver` class to save and restore models in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have just trained a model using Tensorflow and I want to save it and restore it later. I read the [Saving and Restoring page](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model) in official documentation of Tensorflow and I stumbled by the following code to save a model

```
export_dir = ...
...
builder = tf.saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                       [tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                       signature_def_map=foo_signatures,
                                       assets_collection=foo_assets)
...
# Add a second MetaGraphDef for inference.
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph([tag_constants.SERVING])
...
builder.save()
```

but I couldn't understand what are `[tag_constants.TRAINING]` list and `[tag_constants.SERVING]` list.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to just be used to identify which `MetaGraphDef` you want to restore.  The existing tags are `SERVING`, `TRAINING`, and `GPU`, but you can define your own using something like `tf.saved_model.tag_constants.MEOW = "kitty!"`.